# MemberExpression to MemberExpression[]

Tags: linq, performance, reflection, lambda, linq-expressions

The objective is to get an array of MemberExpressions from two LambdaExpressions.  The first is convertible to a MethodCallExpression that returns the instance of an object (`Expression<Func<T>>`).  The second Lambda expression would take the result of the compiled first expression and return a nested member (`Expression<Func<T,TMember>>`).  We can assume that the second Lambda expression will only make calls to nested properties, but may do several of these calls.

So, the signature of the method I am trying to create is :

`MemberExpression[] GetMemberExpressionArray<T,TValue>(Expression<Func<T>> instanceExpression, Expression<Func<T,TValue>> nestedMemberExpression)`

where `nestedMemberExpression` will be assumed to take an argument of the form

`parent => parent.ChildProperty.GrandChildProperty`

and the resulting array represents the MemberAccess from `parent` to `ChildProperty` and from the value of `ChildProperty` to `GrandChildProperty`.

I have already returned the last `MemberExpression` using the following extension method.

```
public static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<T, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression)
{
    if (expression == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (expression.Body is MemberExpression)
    {
        return (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    }
    if (expression.Body is UnaryExpression)
    {
        var operand = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand;
        if (operand is MemberExpression)
        {
            return (MemberExpression)operand;
        }
        if (operand is MethodCallExpression)
        {
            return ((MethodCallExpression)operand).Object as MemberExpression;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, I know there are several ways to accomplish this.  The most immediately intuitive to me would be to loop through the `.Expression` property to get the first expression and capture references to each MemberExpression along the way.  This may be the best way to do it, but it may not.  I am not extraordinarily familiar with the performance costs I get from using expressions like this.  I know a MemberExpression has a MemberInfo and that reflection is supposed to hurt performance.

I've tried to search for information on expressions, but my resources have been very limited in what I've found.

I would appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this task (and this type of task, in general) with optimal performance and reliability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this has been tagged *performance*, but the *easiest* way I can think of to extract member-expressions from a tree  is to subclass [**`ExpressionVisitor`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitmember.aspx). This should be much simpler than manually writing the logic to 'expand' different types of expressions and walk the tree.

You'll probably have to override the [`VisitMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitmember.aspx) method so that:

1. Each member-expression is captured.
2. Its children are visited.

I imagine that would look something like:

```
protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
{
    _myListOfMemberExpressions.Add(node);
    return base.VisitMember(node);
}
```

I'm slightly unclear about the remainder of your task; it appears like you want to *rewrite* parameter-expressions, in which case you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861827/inject-param-value-for-tdelegate-in-expressiontdelegate-and-reduce-expression/4862129#4862129) from Marc Gravell.