# Inject param value for TDelegate in Expression<TDelegate> and reduce expression

Tags: c#, linq

I need to reduce an expression

`Expression<Func<TQueryResult, TParam, bool>>`

to

`Expression<Func<TQueryResult, bool>>`

by injecting `TParam value` as a constant into the expression.

Concrete example:

```
protected IQueryable<TQueryResult> AddQueryFilter<TQueryResult, TParam>(IQueryable<TQueryResult> query, Expression<Func<TQueryResult, TParam, bool>> exp,  TParam param)
{
    object obj = param;

    if (obj is string)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string) obj))
        {
            var reducedExp = new Expression<Func<TQueryResult, bool>>()
            // ...
            // the magic that I need to inject param value
            //..
            return query.Where(reducedExp);
        }
    }
    else if (obj is DateTime)
    {
        //... return query.Where(reducedExp); 
    }
    else
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Param type not supported");

    return query;
}

//usage

var qr = Manager.Invoices.Query;
qr = AddQueryFilter(qr, (invoice, value) => value == invoice.Number, numberEdit.Text);
qr = AddQueryFilter(qr, (invoice, value) => value == invoice.Date, dateEdit.Date);
qr = AddQueryFilter(qr, (invoice, value) => invoice.Description.Contains(value), descEdit.Text);
```

Comment: is AddQueryFilter === ConstructSearchExpression ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Which LINQ implementation are you using? LINQ-to-SQL? to EF? what?

Comment: To EF. But I don't see how that matters, I'm just trying to reduce a general expression no matter the backend.

Comment: @Boris it matters because EF doesn't support `Expression.Invoke` (LINQ-to-SQL does). This means you need to re-write the expression tree completely.

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717444/combining-two-lamba-expressions-in-c) - let me see if that does the job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
protected static IQueryable<TQueryResult> AddQueryFilter<TQueryResult, TParam>(
    IQueryable<TQueryResult> query, Expression<Func<TQueryResult, TParam, bool>> exp, TParam param)
{

    var rewriter = new ExpressionRewriter();
    rewriter.Subst(exp.Parameters[1], Expression.Constant(param, typeof(TParam)));
    var body = rewriter.Apply(exp.Body);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TQueryResult, bool>>(body, exp.Parameters[0]);
    return query.Where(lambda);
}
```

using `ExpressionRewriter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717444/combining-two-lamba-expressions-in-c).

Comment: It works for `invoice.Number == value`; also works for `invoice.Number.ToLower() == value.ToLower()`; but does not work for `invoice.Number.Contains(value)`, it fails in ExpressionRewriter.Walk { case ExpressionType.Call: } - "Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: method"

Comment: @Boris - odd; that isn't a static method - I can repro, will investigate a little later

Comment: @Boris - found and fixed; see the change to `Walk` around `ExpressionType.Parameter`

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work now. I was hoping to understand the solution to this, but this seems somewhat over my head :)

Comment: @Boris expression trees take a bit of brain-ache to appreciate, for sure. Very powerful when you grok them fully, though

Answer (score 0):

I hope somebody still can be searching for this topic, as me, in fact, so I'd like to suggest the following possibility.

Since .NET 4.0 has been released, you can use built-in [expression tree visitors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here's an exapmple, which implements required functionality:

```
private class ExpressionConstantInjector<T, TConstant> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly TConstant toInject;
    private readonly ParameterExpression targetParam;

    public EntityExpressionListInjector(TConstant toInject)
    {
        this.toInject = toInject;
        targetParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
    }

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Inject(Expression<Func<T, TConstant, bool>> source)
    {
        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>) VisitLambda(source);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T1>(Expression<T1> node)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda(Visit(node.Body), targetParam);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type == typeof (TConstant))
            return Expression.Constant(toInject);
        return targetParam;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Expression<Func<Entity, List<int>, bool>> expression = (e, ids) => ids.Contains(e.Id);

var filterExpression 
    = new ExpressionConstantInjector<Entity, List<int>>(new List<int>{1, 2, 3})
    .Inject(expression); 
// filterExpression is like a => (1, 2, 3).Contains(a.Id) 
// filterExpression can be passed to EF IQueryables.
```

This solution is very local, not really reusable, but quiet simple (nah).

To be honest, `[].Contains(id)` is the only case I've tested. But I think it works.